# Kivy VM Buildozer Command Failed

Tags: android, python, linux, kivy, buildozer

I recently learned about kivy and tried to make a very simple little app just to test  it. To try it out properly I used the kivy launcher but also felt compelled to try and compile it to an APK for my android phone. So I downloaded virtual box and installed linux mint on it. After installing things like java, cython and all that good stuff I tried to run "buildozer android debug". It keeps returning this bug though and I can't seem to figure out why. Any input is appreciated, thanks!

```
Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_nam
e=vibapplication --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-
libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_python/python projects/kivy_learn/vi
brator/.buildozer/android/platform/build
```

Full log: https://jpst.it/17q2O

Comment: You should provide additional information, like the reason it failed.

Comment: I added the full log and the "command failed" error message. Not sure what more information I can provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try installing Buildozer VM from this link

https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html

also you may follow https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#buildozer

make sure you run "buildozer init" inside your project folder and also you have main.py file which is your program file and then run "buildozer android debug"

Note: you may also update the buildozer.spec file as per your requirement.

requirement = kivy # this should be by default

Comment: I appreciate your answer and while I have already tried those things I thought i'd give it another shot. However this simply returned another error.

Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"

And here is the full log: https://jpst.it/17sZ3

Comment: # Run './distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"'
# Cwd /media/sf_python/python projects/kivy_learn/vibrator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Check build dependencies for Ubuntu
Packages missing: cython   ====> "Cython missing here"
It might break the compilation, except if you installed thoses packages manually.
Check environment

Comment: from the log you shared looks like Cython is missing, so did you installed it already? if yes, what is the version? Try install Cython==0.25 and run the buildozer android debug

Comment: I tried installing cython using your suggestion but got a message stating that cython is already installed. Afterwards I just received the same error

https://jpst.it/17t3Y

Comment: What is the Cython version already installed?  do #pip freeze and also  #pip3 freeze and look for the Cython version please, do you have two version python running i mean python2 and python3?

Comment: Yes the kivy VM comes with python 2 and 3. #pip freeze shows that the Cython version is 0.25 and pip3 shows Cython version 0.25 too. The program i'm trying to compile is written with python 3, not sure if that matters.

Again the log is saying: "rm: cannot remove '/media/sf_python'$'\n''projects/kivy_learn/vibrator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp': Permission denied"

And here's the full log: https://jpst.it/17wey

Comment: I fixed the permission denied error and actually made it compile an APK by copying the files away from the shared folder an into the desktop on the VM. Now i'm facing another issue that is when launching the app it just crashes instantly. But seeing as how my initial problem was solved i'll mark the problem as resolved. Thanks for the help